# How to find the K value in the probability inequality of binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
dist = BinomialDistribution[100, 1/3]

Solve[{PDF[dist, k] >= PDF[dist, k - 1], 
   PDF[dist, k] >= PDF[dist, k + 1]}, k] // FullSimplify
```

In this binomial distribution, when the value of K is, the probability value is the largest?

K is an integer between 0 and 100

No results are displayed, what's going on?

Comment: It's not that "No results are displayed".  A message is produced:  "Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."  Please include all warning messages in your questions.

Comment: Specify an interval and the domain: `Solve[{PDF[dist, k] >= PDF[dist, k - 1], 
  PDF[dist, k] >= PDF[dist, k + 1], 0 <= k <= 100}, k, Integers]`

Comment: @BobHanlon How can I obtain the range of k values?

Comment: From the `PDF`, i.e., `PDF[dist, k][[1, 1, -1]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dist = BinomialDistribution[100, 1/3];
Maximize[PDF[dist, k], k, Integers] // N
```

> {0.0843827, {k -> 33.}}

```
DiscretePlot[
 PDF[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/3], k] // Evaluate, {k, 50}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `Integers` to the end of `Maximize` gives the correct result.

Comment: Thanks @JimB for the tip. I have corrected it.

Comment: How can I obtain the range of k values?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly then you are trying to get the max of a Binomial distribution. This problem is easily solved analytically. For a Binomial distribution with n trials and a success rate of p, the max of the PDF is:

```
Ceiling[n p-(1-p)]
```

For your example:

```
n=100;
p=1/3.;
```

this gives:

```
max=  Ceiling[n p-(1-p)]

33
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dist = BinomialDistribution[100, 1/3];


Median @ dist
```

> 33

Comment: Median is the value for which half the probability mass is greater, and half the probability mass is lesser.  For an arbitrary distribution the median need *NOT* be the *mode*, which is what is what is being asked.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, the question _is_ about BinomialDistribution:)